# TFS build partially succeeded when calling a batch file, but no error in log

Tags: tfs, batch-file, tfsbuild

I’m building a solution which requires a batch file to be run after the build (there's a sequence in the workflow for this). TFS flags the build as partially succeeded, but there’s no error in the log even in full verbose mode ("diagnostic"). I’m checking the **errorlevel** after each line in the batch file and it’s always 0. I’ve also tested redirecting **stdout** and **stderr** in a file after each line and there’s no clue there.

It’s got nothing to do with unit tests because I’m skipping them for the time being.

I’ve noticed that usually when an error occurs in a batch file (e.g. file not found) there’s a visual cue to indicate the error and this matches the partially succeeded status. But I don’t see any visual cue.

So how can TFS decide that the build is only partially succeeded?

Thank you,

Comment: Run the build in Diagnostic mode and trace through using the output what happened.  If it's showing partially succeeded, somewhere it went into the workflow where it set that result value.  If you run it in Diagnostic mode you can see exactly what happened.

Comment: Dylan, do you mean that I should see a line where the build result is set in the log? I don't. And I don't see any red circles, as opposed to when there's a deliberate error in the batch file.

Comment: Did you run it in diagnostic mode?  It shows you in great detail every activity that is run in the build.  You want to look at every SetBuildProperties activity, to see what the CompilationStatus, TestStatus and/or Status are being set to throughout the build.

Comment: Yes I ran it in diagnostic mode but I can't see any Status being set to PartiallySucceeded. Do I have to explicitly call a SetBuildProperties activity at the end of my InvokeProcess activity to handle the Status? I assumed this was handled by TFS.

Comment: PartiallySucceeded usually means that CompilationStatus = Success and TestStatus = Failed (or vice versa).  Check where those BuildProperties are set and it should lead you to the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

It turns out the **GetImpactedTests** activity is throwing an exception (I can see it in the event viewer of the TFS machine), but it doesn't show at all in the build log.

I'm guessing that this exception makes the build partially succeeded (because the compilation part succeeded)  but I couldn't see the assignment explicitly in the buid log. When I bypass the impact analysis (either by setting Analyze Test Impact to False or by removing the GetImpactedTests activity altogether), the error does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

We experiment something similar here using the Lab Workflow (to kick our CodedUI tests).  Different build template, same symptoms.

I have noticed that the build process reports that it partially succeeded, highlighting what seems to be a successful step in the deploy script (batch file).

The command is question is a command to install our mobile app on a mobile device (in order to test it at night):

```
adb install -d -r test.apk
```

I thought about looking the errorlevel right after running the adb command but the errorlevel was 0.

Then I thought that maybe the command is sending its output to **stderr** and found out this article on the [android open source project](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=229529), which confirms my hypothesis.

Following is my fix:

```
adb install -r -d test.apk  2>&1
```

Appending **2>&1** simply redirects stderr to stdout and now my deploy script does not report an error anymore and the build now succeeds (when all tests pass!).

**Conclusion**:  When a script writes anything to **stderr**, the build workflow will report it as an error (partial success since it does not prevent execution of the workflow).

I know this is not your particular issue but since we had the same symptoms, I thought the **stderr** information could help somebody else find out the reason why their build process is reporting a partial success even though everything seems to work.